# Why does the global git config "remote.origin.push" override the local "remote.origin.push"?

Tags: git, git-config

```
# git version 2.22.0.windows.1

# create simulation repos
git init --bare server
git init client

# set global and local config
git config --global remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
cd client
git remote add origin ../server
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*

# create and push "master"
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m foo
git push origin master
```

It's expected that the local refspec `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` would work. However `refs/for/master` is created instead. I delete `refs/for/master` and try with `-c`:

```
git push origin :refs/for/master
git -c remote.origin.push=refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* push origin master
```

Again `refs/for/master` is created instead of `refs/heads/master`.

I delete `remote.origin.push` in the global config and try again, and then `refs/heads/master` is created as expected. And also I make these tests.

```
global refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
local  refs/heads/*:refs/hello/*
result refs/for/master

global refs/heads/*:refs/hello/*
local  refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
result refs/hello/master

global refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
local  unset
result refs/for/master

global unset
local  refs/heads/*:refs/hello/*
result refs/hello/master
```

I even add a push refspec in system config, which leads to an unexpected result, too.

```
system refs/heads/*:refs/world/*
global refs/heads/*:refs/hello/*
local  refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
result refs/world/master
```

And test `user.name`,

```
system systemname
global globalname
local  localname
result localname
```

It turns out that for `remote.origin.push` the precedence order is reversed compared with other config variables.

I'm quite confused as it does not work as I have believed. Is this a bug or have I missed any subtle feature of git config?

Comment: Both `fetch` and `push` refspecs *add*, rather than overriding, as bk2204 answered (beat me to it).

Comment: @torek thanks. Is this documented?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen. It's obvious from the source: https://github.com/git/git/blob/0aae918dd929862d3ce0ea2960897787bb269a3b/remote.c#L352-L402 Note the two `refspec_append` calls.

Comment: Thanks @torek. It makes sense. But `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/for/master refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` and `git push origin refs/heads/*:refs/for/* refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` behave differently. I think `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` is also a refspec. Am I right or wrong? The push refspec is stored in git config, but does not follow its precedence order. I somehow find it a bit odd.

Comment: If you use a command-line refspec, Git ignores all the read-from-config refspecs (true for both fetch and push). Meanwhile, the entries in config are read in the order: system, global, user, `--file`. So the "append" ops leave the most-local at the end. For non-appending, overriding values, the last write is the only one you can see, so that the most-local value takes precedence. Perhaps Git should use insert-at-front instead of append-at-end for cumulative config file items. (But you'd probably want the in-file entries to be in file order!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it's not that the configuration is being read in a different order, but that push refspecs are additive. In other words, it's possible to specify multiple push refspec options in `remote.<remote>.push` and they all take effect in the order that they are read from the config file.

However, Git will only push a set of source refs to one place. Since you've already specified a destination for `refs/heads/*` (by listing it in an earlier configuration file), no later destination will override it. You can see this by listing both on the command line:

```
$ git push $TMP/test-repo refs/heads/*:refs/for/* refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
Enumerating objects: 105, done.
Counting objects: 100% (105/105), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
Writing objects: 100% (105/105), 32.96 KiB | 3.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 105 (delta 41), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (41/41), done.
To /tmp/user/1000/test-repo
 * [new branch]      master -> refs/for/master
```

So if your global config file had specified `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` and your local configuration file had specified `refs/heads/*:refs/for/*`, then both would take effect, because they don't overlap.

If you want different behavior in this case, you either need to remove the global and system configuration, or switch the remote name in the local repository.

Comment: Updated and thanks for the answer. But I'm still not that convinced. I also tried `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/foo/master refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`. Both `refs/for/master` and `refs/heads/master` were created. I wonder why glob refspec behaves different from specified refspec.

Comment: Thanks. Much is explained in the source in @torek comment. I'll accept your answer.